# Filter SharePoint List differently in context of logged in user

Tags: 2010, list, filter, view

I have a list view with a filter matching according to a people picker column called Manager is equal to [Me] so that Managers see their own records.

The creation of the records are initially done by another department who should see all records so I'd like to add a filter so if the logged in user is a member of a certain group they see everything.

Do you know of a way to achieve this?  I've looked into OTTB Views and Filters, JavaScript or editing the filter in SharePoint designer but have drawn up a blank.

Comment: The department that are managing the list, can't they create an individual list view that show every record?

Comment: They will have to manually create it themselves but once set it's done so that looks like it will do the trick! I was over complicating it as I thought the views were locked down but they can still create Personal Views as you have pointed out.  Much appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The property that you are looking for is Target Audience in the web part properties.

1. Create a new view with the filter based on the creators groups.
2. Create a new page or edit your existing page and add both views in that page, one below the other.
3. Set the Target Audience in web part properties of the page.

The target audience so works that if it is empty, no access control is performed. If it contains a user or group, the web part is made visible only if that user is logged-in or the user belongs to the group specified.

Regards